# I am writing a Java program that compares a .xlsx file and a .csv file, unsure how to directly compare cell values between the two files

Tags: java, excel, csv, xlsx

I am writing a Java program that will read data from a .xlsx file and a .csv file, and compare the respective values for each cell between the two sheets to find differences.  I have been able to successfully write a script that compares the sizes of the two files, then iterates through each cell and prints the values to the console.  That code is as follows:

```
package sodapackage;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class CompareCSVandXLSX {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            //Retrieves .xlsx Workbook and sheet
            XSSFWorkbook XLSXWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive - Computer Aid, Inc\\Desktop\\Test Data.xlsx"));
            XSSFSheet XLSXSheet = XLSXWorkbook.getSheet("Test Data");
            System.out.println(".xlsx file found");

            //Finds the last row and column in .xlsx sheet to determine number of rows and columns
            int XLSXRows = XLSXSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            int XLSXCols = XLSXSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

            //Retrieves .csv Workbook
            Scanner CSVWorkbook = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive - Computer Aid, Inc\\Desktop\\Test Data_1.csv")));
            System.out.println(".csv file found");

            //Parses each line in .csv file to find the number of rows and columns
            int CSVCols = 0;
            int CSVRows = 0;
            CSVWorkbook.useDelimiter(",");
            while (CSVWorkbook.hasNextLine()) {
                String CSVline = CSVWorkbook.nextLine();
                String[] CSVArray = CSVline.split(",");
                CSVRows++;
                CSVCols = CSVArray.length;
            }

            //Verifies both files have same number of rows
            if (CSVRows == XLSXRows) {
                System.out.println("Rows match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Rows do not match");
            }

            //Verifies both files have same number of columns
            if (CSVCols == XLSXCols) {
                System.out.println("Columns match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Columns do not match");
            }

            //Reads each cell in .xlsx sheet
            Iterator < Row > XLSXRowIterator = XLSXSheet.iterator();
            while (XLSXRowIterator.hasNext()) {
                //Sets row to be read
                Row XLSXRow = XLSXRowIterator.next();
                Iterator < org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell > XLSXCellIterator = XLSXRow.cellIterator();

                //Reads each cell in current row and prints cell value
                while (XLSXCellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell Cell = XLSXCellIterator.next();
                    String XLSXCell = Cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(XLSXCell + "\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");

            //Re-establishes .csv filepath for CSVReader
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive - Computer Aid, Inc\\Desktop\\Test Data_1.csv"));

            String CSVCell[];

            //Reads and prints out each .csv cell value
            while ((CSVCell = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < CSVCell.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(CSVCell[i] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want the script to directly compare cell values across files (i.e. XLSX Cell A1 = CSV Cell A1) and print the results to the console.  I am not sure how to achieve this.

I tried to insert a block of code after the CSVReader portion of the script that compares the XLSX Cell and CSVCell values.  The resulting code looks like this:

```
package sodapackage;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class CompareCSVandXLSX {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            //Retrieves .xlsx Workbook and sheet
            XSSFWorkbook XLSXWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive - Computer Aid, Inc\\Desktop\\Test Data.xlsx"));
            XSSFSheet XLSXSheet = XLSXWorkbook.getSheet("Test Data");
            System.out.println(".xlsx file found");

            //Finds the last row and column in .xlsx sheet to determine number of rows and columns
            int XLSXRows = XLSXSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            int XLSXCols = XLSXSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

            //Retrieves .csv Workbook
            Scanner CSVWorkbook = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive - Computer Aid, Inc\\Desktop\\Test Data_1.csv")));
            System.out.println(".csv file found");

            //Parses each line in .csv file to find the number of rows and columns
            int CSVCols = 0;
            int CSVRows = 0;
            CSVWorkbook.useDelimiter(",");
            while (CSVWorkbook.hasNextLine()) {
                String CSVline = CSVWorkbook.nextLine();
                String[] CSVArray = CSVline.split(",");
                CSVRows++;
                CSVCols = CSVArray.length;
            }

            //Verifies both files have same number of rows
            if (CSVRows == XLSXRows) {
                System.out.println("Rows match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Rows do not match");
            }

            //Verifies both files have same number of columns
            if (CSVCols == XLSXCols) {
                System.out.println("Columns match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Columns do not match");
            }

            //Reads each cell in .xlsx sheet
            Iterator < Row > XLSXRowIterator = XLSXSheet.iterator();
            while (XLSXRowIterator.hasNext()) {
                //Sets row to be read
                Row XLSXRow = XLSXRowIterator.next();
                Iterator < org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell > XLSXCellIterator = XLSXRow.cellIterator();

                //Reads each cell in current row and prints cell value
                while (XLSXCellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell Cell = XLSXCellIterator.next();
                    String XLSXCell = Cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(XLSXCell + "\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");

            //Re-establishes .csv filepath for CSVReader
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive - Computer Aid, Inc\\Desktop\\Test Data_1.csv"));

            String CSVCell[];

            //Reads and prints out each .csv cell value
            while ((CSVCell = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < CSVCell.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(CSVCell[i] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            //Compares cell values and determines if they match or not
            if (XLSXCell == CSVCell) {
                System.out.printIn(XLSXCell, CSVCell, "Cells match");
            } else {
                System.out.printIn(XLSXCell, CSVCell, "Cells do not match");
            }

        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the system does not seem to recognize the XLSXCell variable in the part where cell values are compared. I think it would make sense for the code from the row iterator to the cell comparison be part of one loop, but I am unsure of how to accomplish this.  What is the best way to compare cell values in .xlsx and .csv files?

Comment: How about aligning the formats before comparison? That would boil down to simple import/export filter (make up your mind which of the formats you prefer to compare) and then stay in the preferred format, just comparing the values. There are two excellent java libs Apache POI and Apache commons CSV.

Comment: Please check out the [ask] link as well as the [question editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link.

Comment: I have just now tried to format your code, but in the future, this is something that you should be doing yourself.

Comment: @Queeg So your suggestion is to convert one of the two documents into the other's format?  I agree that is probably a much easier way to go about this script.  I just wanted to see if there was a method for direct comparison.

Comment: @Queeg What actions are you referring to when you say import/export filter.  Are there any other JARs I will have to download/packages to import?

Comment: I am not aware these filters already exist in the libraries I named - however I was referring to architecture. Creating an import or export filter is generic, so chances of finding an implementation is easier. If you cannot find one, writing one is still more reusable than implementing your intended comparison of XLSX to CSV.